# Large number of undefined references and unrecognized command line option for -ip

Tags: compiler-errors, mpi, intel

I'm compiling some Fortran code and can't seem to make it work with the Intel compilers. I'm currently utilizing the `mpif90` to compile it. It runs for a while and then fails when it suddenly throws a ton of undefined references and gives up. I'm using Intel Parallel Studio XE 2018.

I have only exported `psxevars.sh` in the environment variables.

I have tried using `mpiifort` `mpifort` `ifort` but all of these just give up right after compiling. I have had most progress with mpif90.

Also, one of the flags predefined in the `Makefile` had `-ip` under `FXXOPT`. Using it also fails the compilation with `unrecognized command line option` error. I am new to compiling Fortran and could use some serious help. Thank you.

edit:

compiling with `mpiifort` gives the error

```
eval: ifort: not found
```

the compiler options were

```
FXXOPT = -O2 -ip
```

and the linked libraries were

```
LIB_BLAS =-L$(MKLDIR) -lmkl_scalapack_lp64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 
-lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lmkl_blacs
```

`MKLDIR` has been pointed at relevant folder.

Comment: are you sure `mpif90` invokes `ifort` and *not* `gfortran` ? `mpiifort` definitely invokes `ifort`. if you need more help, please provide more information such as compiler invokation and error message.

Comment: replacing mpif90 with mpiifort gives `eval : ifort : not found`

Comment: is `ifort` installed ? what does `which ifort` says ? you might have to source  some more files (e.g. `. /.../compilervars.sh intel64`) in order to use `ifort`. iirc `-ip` is an intel option, not a gnu one